# Не могу удалить символы из элементов словаря

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

Есть большой список похожий на

```
[{'phone': [' 8 (911) 111-11-11'], 'telegram': [' @sssss'], 'link': 'https://ssssss', 'specs': ['Программирование и IT — Программирование для сотовых и КПК\xa0]}]
```

Не могу разобраться как мне на выходе убрать @, [, \xa0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После \xa0 должна быть закрывающая кавычка иначе пример словаря не рабочий.
Если это решаемо то попробуйте такой вариант:

```py
a = [{'phone': [' 8 (911) 111-11-11'], 'telegram': [' @sssss'], 'link': 'https://ssssss', 'specs': ['Программирование и IT — Программирование для сотовых и КПК\xa0']}]

for n, i in enumerate(a):
    for n2, l in enumerate(i["specs"]):
        if "\xa0" in l:
            a[n]["specs"][n2] = l.replace("\xa0", "")

print(a)
```

Аналогично для любых других элементов.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо